# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE-like behaviour on multiple columns

Tags: php, mariadb

I have a table like this:

```
id | userid | commentid | value
-------------------------------
```

Each user is permitted to vote a comment once. The value can be between -1 and 1. Is there a easy way for a table model to achieve an change of this vote in one single query, without checking EXISTS() first? I already thought about a hash-column like this

```
MD5(CONCAT(userid, commentid))
```

but is there any better solution for this?

Comment: `on duplicate key update` should work just fine, as long as you have a unique index spanning `userid` and `commentid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an unique key on `userid` + `commentid` and you can use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

```
INSERT INTO `yourTable` (
  `userid`,
  `commentid`,
  `value`
) VALUES (
  x,
  y,
  z
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  `value` = z
```